# scroll to focused item in listbox dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have two list box in `WPF` which looks something like this:
[image]

Lets say, the left one is lbLeft and right one is lbRight.
 The **">"** button adds one selected item from lbLeft to lbRight. And, **"<"** removes the selected item form lbRight from the list.
 The **">>"** adds all the item from lbLeft to lbRight and **"<<"** clears lbRight.
When I double click an item from lbLeft, it is added to the lbLeft and that newly added item is **focused**. Also, if i try to add an item from lbLeft which already exists in lbRight, it places a focus in that selected item(so that items are not repeated). But when lots of item are added in lbRight, I have to manually scroll down to the point where focus is placed. How can I make the scrolling of `listbox` automatic to the point where focus is placed?

I have done the following:

```
    private void select_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // > button
    {
        addingItemToSelectedList();
    }

    private void remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // < button
    {
        if (lbRight.SelectedItem != null) {
            lbRight.Items.RemoveAt(lbRight.SelectedIndex);
        }
    }

    private void selectall_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // >> button
    {
        lbRight.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string item in column1) {
            lbRight.Items.Add(item);
        }

    }

private void lbLeft_MouseDoubleClick_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        addingItemToSelectedList();
    }
    private void addingItemToSelectedList() {
        if (lbLeft.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            string item = lbLeft.SelectedItem.ToString();
            addFocus(item);
        }
    }
    private void addFocus(string item) {
        if (!lbRight.Items.Contains(item))
        {
            lbRight.Items.Add(item);
            lbRight.SelectedIndex = lbRight.Items.Count - 1;
            lbRight.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            int index = lbRight.Items.IndexOf(item);
            lbRight.SelectedIndex = index;
            lbRight.Focus();
        }
    }
    private void removeall_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //<< button
    {
        lbRight.ItemsSource = null;
        lbRight.Items.Clear();
    }
```

column1 in the code is a list of items which populate lbLeft.
**UPDATE:**
I tried to use `lbRight.ScrollIntoView(lbRight.SelectedIndex);` But it has no effect

Comment: Maybe this stackoverflow question can help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926722/get-first-visible-item-in-wpf-listview-c-sharp

Comment: I looked into it but it got me all confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ScrollIntoView()` worked now. What i had to do was: 

`lbRight.ScrollIntoView(lbRight.Items[lbRight.SelectedIndex]);`
It now passes the actual item rather than index of it.