# C# Scroll to top of listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Ive seen lots of posts which show how to scroll to bottom item of a ListBox, but cant work out how to autoscroll to the top of the listbox.
If I scroll down my listbox, then use my filter function, the listbox will stay at the position you have scrolled down to, so the user may not see the results which are above where they are scrolled down to.

Ive been trying to use the listbox.ScrollIntoView but cannot get the right function. this is the context of where it would be... (commented part):

```
private void filter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string filterString = textBox1.Text;
    XElement _xml = XElement.Load("1/1.xml");
    {
        results.Items.Clear();
        foreach (XElement value in _xml.Elements("Operators").Elements("Operator"))
        {
            1Item _item = new 1Item();
            _item.TradingName = value.Element("TradingName").Value;

            if (_item.Town.IndexOf(filterString, 0, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
            {
                results.Items.Add(_item);
                // add scroll function here
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
if(results.Items.Count > 0)
    results.ScrollIntoView(results.Items[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems spot on, but its not doing the job for some reason. no errors or anything, just not functioning?! Odd.

Comment: Are you calling `ScrollIntoView` outside of the foreach loop ?

Comment: Yes. If i get rid of all the XML and listbox populating code, and just have your line in the method, it returns the lsitbox to the top as it should.

Comment: Ok, Ive put your line at as the first line of my method, and it works fine. Many thanks!

Comment: @BalaR Simple and effective answer. +1

Comment: @BalaR, your solution doesn't work if ListBox contains grouping. It would scroll to the first item but group header would still stay hidden. -1

Answer (score 3):

`ScrollIntoView` didn't work for me, but this did:

```
VisualTreeHelperEx.FindDescendantByType<ScrollViewer>(YourListView)?.ScrollToTop();
```

This uses the [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) to get the ScrollViewer, but you can of course do it manually e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1080012/325442).

Comment: May be it didn't work for you because it needs the dispatcher to be invoked

Answer (score 0):

One important notice to the @Bala-R 's answer (And why it did work for @Mr-Bungle) is that if you're calling the ScrollIntoView from another thread or component, you need to also invoke dispatcher:

```
    public async Task ScrollToTop()
    {
        await this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
            if (lstRecords.Items.Count > 0)
                lstRecords.ScrollIntoView(lstRecords.Items[0]);
        });
    }
```