# How to achieve the same behavior of the scrollviewer in a web page in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I want to be able to click and jump to a section of the app using the scrollviewer. I understad we can use the BringIntoView() method, but it does not place the element I want to focus on at the top? Any Tips?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm guessing that it places the element you want to focus on the bottom? Probably because you were above your element. Have you tried first scrolling all to the end, and then calling BringIntoView()?

Comment: While this answer is using a ListView, it should point you in the right direction. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49101385/5858936