# How to know if a displayed listboxItem is in a WPF ListBox

Tags: wpf, listbox, itemrenderer

How do I know if the rendered listboxItem is in a WPF ListBox?
I want to get the list box items that are displayed in the screen, because I want to move the item at the bottom to the top of the screen like when auto-scrolling.

I already searched Google, but couldn't find an answer, and I used a method like below but it didn't work on rendered items:

```
MyViewModel myViewModel = LbList.Items.getItemAt(0);
LbChatList.ScrollIntoView(myViewModel);
```

Comment: You can use the ListBox's ItemContainerGenerator to find the number of items in the viewport, and then you can iterate through those and check the visibility of the containers, but I don't think you're going to be able to produce the behaviour you are after with a standard ListBox. ScrollIntoView isn't going to give you that kind of behaviour. You need to write a custom control from scratch

Comment: @DeanChalk Thanks for your reply. i got two information about ListBox.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When asking it's important to use clear language. If English isn't your primary language feel free to ask a peer to review your question and help clarify it. This helps avoid problems when we try to understand and/or correct it. See "[ask]" and the linked pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "[Scroll ListViewItem to be at the top of a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077397/scroll-listviewitem-to-be-at-the-top-of-a-listview/1080012#1080012)" someone used the listView but I used a listbox instead.

I can get the ScrollViewer more easily using:

```
ScrollViewer myScrollviwer = FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(myListBoxObject);
```

Comment: Is this supposed to answer your question? If not, please consider editing your question instead.

Comment: @Clemens yes it is my answer to my question. i solve my problem with it